# Dojo Dialog dont want to block whole page only fragement/div of the page

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, portlet

Hi I am working on Dojo and Liferay portal.

We have portlets which are using Dojo for UI. We want to show dialog  ( "Loading..." dialog) for each of the portlets (Divs/Fragments...). Problem is each Dialog block access to whole page,and there are more than one such dialogs would be there.

Can we customize/change to restrict Dojo Dialog's "Modalness" to particular div/fragment rather than whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

check out the new Release of Dojo. It is version 1.4ß witch has better dialog widgets included.

[Dojo 1.4](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/2009/10/12/dojo-1-4-beta)

```
* Multiple dialogs can now be shown (with one dialog launching over another).
* Dialog supports aria-describedby to make it more accessible to screen readers.
```